# What is the "Not" sign in batch

Tags: batch-file

In batch, saying `if %stackoverflow%==something` the `==` means equals

What is the "not" version of this?

I have tried "!=" however that only throws an error, and dont really know if there is a "not" command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
if not %stackoverflow%==something
```

and if you want to do a case-insensitive compare add /i:

```
if /i not %stackoverflow%==something
```

Comment: I didnt know that you could use if not, but that should work!

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, this has helped a lot, in both clearing up the first answer's faults and also the new answer!

Answer (score 5):

John D got the original not operator available to batch programming.

```
if not a==b echo ok
```

Use HELP IF to see all the available operators that were introduced with command extensions

```
If Command Extensions are enabled IF changes as follows:

    IF [/I] string1 compare-op string2 command
    IF CMDEXTVERSION number command
    IF DEFINED variable command

where compare-op may be one of:

    EQU - equal
    NEQ - not equal
    LSS - less than
    LEQ - less than or equal
    GTR - greater than
    GEQ - greater than or equal
```

So a not equal condition can be written as

```
if a neq b echo ok
```